# Objective C integer array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object, integer

I have an array called **binaryArray**.

Initalised with `NSMutableArray *binaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

I add 0's or 1's into the array using `[binaryArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];`

I then reference this array in a tableView with

```
id resultBinary = [binaryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if (resultBinary == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
```

However, even if `resultBinary` is **0**, it never hits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NSNumber is a class that helps to store numeric types as object. So when comparing with 1, it is actually comparing with numeric type not with NSNumber.

So changing it to NSNumber literals works.

```
id resultBinary = [binaryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if ([resultBinary isEqual:@0]) {
        [cell.starImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Results_star_empty"]];
    } else {
        [cell.starImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Results_star_filled"]];
    }
```

[Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ([resultBinary integerValue] == 0) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```